# How to test if a variable is primitive in PHP

Tags: php, primitive-types

What would be the best (most efficient, easiest to understand in the code, etc) way to check whether a variable is of primitive type in PHP?

Should I go the "positive" (e.g. `is_string() || is_int()...)` way, or vice versa `!is_array() && __is_object()..` or maybe some even fancier way?

Comment: I, personally, would stick with `is_<type>()`; they are there for a reason (always try to retain clarity and purpose for later down the road).

Comment: a) use **breiti**'s answer b) **definitely** positive way - you never know what new type will pop-out - better approach is consider any other as non-primitive :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are looking for [is_scalar()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-scalar.php).

Comment: is_scalar() will actually only works for boolean, integer, float (double) and string. Because the question talk about primitive types which also are array, object, resource and NULL your answer will not always work.

Comment: @Pier-AlexandreBouchard Arrays and Objects are generally considered not really elementary-primitive (especially not Objects), NULL is a special "type" ... not really a type at all ..., and resource just happens to be built upon integers => can change in time :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the is_type() positive one, as it's more logical, and in tired times you will get confused by all the negatives.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest to read in the code is probably to define an `is_primitive_type()`. I doubt efficiency is any real concern for such a simple operation.